# Build a feed into an Experience Builder app

Tags: arcgis-online-basemaps, arcgis-experience-builder, georss

Can I build a feed into an Experience Builder app? The simplest version I have in mind would be an RSS feed that displays when new records are added to an editable feature layer. A more advanced version would allow users to manually create social media style posts and link them (via hashtag, etc.) to a specific record in the feature layer.